# How do I set evil mode to use the normal state by default in Customize mode?

Tags: evil, customize

When I open the Easy Customization in Emacs, I want to be in `normal` mode instead of `emacs` mode.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following line in your Emacs config:

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'Custom-mode 'normal)
```

**NOTE**: The capitalization of `'Custom-mode` matters here!